# Error:(35, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1

Tags: android, textview

I'm trying to add bubble to a textView as shown in this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EUCF4GdAQ7k
But I'm facing the given problem

Error:(35, 13) Failed to resolve: com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1
Show in File
Show in Project Structure dialog

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read official guideline about **[BubbleView](https://github.com/lguipeng/BubbleView)** . Rectify your `build.gradle` .

```
 allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}

 dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.lguipeng:BubbleView:1.0.1'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your project level gradle file add maven url

```
allprojects {
    repositories {              
       maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}
```